# How do I filter from a resulted array In TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my fake data

```
export const fakeQuestions: Questions[] = [{
    id: '741',
    title: 'Snacks',
    description: 'What is your favorite snack?',
    surveyId: '789',
}, {
    id: '742',
    title: 'Vegetable',
    description: 'What is your favorite veggie?',
    surveyId: '789',
}, {
    id: '147',
    title: 'Cellphone',
    description: 'What is your current cellphone?',
    surveyId: '234',
}];

export const fakeOptions: Options[] = [{
    id: '963',
    title: 'Chips',
    questionId: '741',
}, {
    id: '369',
    title: 'Candys',
    questionId: '741',
}];
```

This is my component ts

```
export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {
  questions: Questions[] = [];
  options: Options[] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.questions = fakeQuestions.filter(questions => questions.surveyId === id);

    this.options = fakeOptions.filter(options => options.questionId === this.questions.id);
  }

}
```

My question is the last line. How do I get a result of options from the questions? For example, array options should have ids 963 and 369 if questionId is 741.

Thank you.

Comment: why not use map function?

Comment: How to use map function?